# C# Console Import Excel to SQL from folder

Tags: c#, sql, excel, import, console

I have this code and it works fine.

```
public partial class CS
{
    static void LoadExcelMain(string excelPath)
    {

        string conString = string.Empty;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(excelPath);
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls":
                conString = @PH_MM_ExcelDataReader.Properties.Settings.Default.Excel03ConString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                conString = @PH_MM_ExcelDataReader.Properties.Settings.Default.Excel07ConString;
                break;
        }
        conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
        using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            excel_con.Open();
            string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

            dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[16] { new DataColumn("MMRequestNo", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("MaterialNumber", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("ProductionVersion",typeof(string)) });

            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
            }
            excel_con.Close();

            string consString = @PH_MM_ExcelDataReader.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = @PH_MM_ExcelDataReader.Properties.Settings.Default.DBTable;

                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("MMRequestNo", "MMRequestNo");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("MaterialNumber", "MaterialNumber");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ProductionVersion", "ProdVersion");
                    con.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                    con.Close();
                    File.Delete(@PH_MM_ExcelDataReader.Properties.Settings.Default.FileLocationPath + "\\Product_Costing_Template.xlsx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
           LoadExcelMain(PH_MM_ExcelDataReader.Properties.Settings.Default.FileLocationPath + "\\Product_Costing_Template.xlsx");
    }
}
```

I also have two tables; one is for the content of the excel file and the other is for the details of the file.

```
tableName: FileDetails
---------------------------------
|FileName|RequestDate|isDone|Logs|
|--------|-----------|------|----|
```

What I want to do is to process according to the RequestDate with this program I have currently only the excel files with "PH" in the start of the filename